# Why can't I resize image in line with text in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I got the image from and followed the instructions from here but for some reason, it's not working.
https://material.io/resources/icons/?search=fire&icon=whatshot&style=baseline
http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/

Here is the instructions they gave:

```
/* Rules for sizing the icon. */
.material-icons.md-18 { font-size: 18px; }
.material-icons.md-24 { font-size: 24px; }
.material-icons.md-36 { font-size: 36px; }
.material-icons.md-48 { font-size: 48px; }
```

This is my html code:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hello</title>

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- CSS Stylesheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>

  <!-- Google icon -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Bootstrap Scripts -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <section class="colored-section" id="title">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Nav Bar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
          <span class="material-icons">
            whatshot
          </span>hello</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#footer">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#cta">Download</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav> </section> </body>
```

And this is my css code:

```
/* Navigation Bar */

.navbar {
  padding: 0 0 4.5rem;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav-item {
  padding: 0 18px;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-family: "Montserrat-Light";
}

.material-icons.md-48 { font-size: 48px; }
```

But no matter what number I change in my css last line, the icon does not become bigger like I want it to. Thanks in advance and thanks for reading

Comment: Do create a snippet

Comment: try using `!important` in the css properties. Do review your code in chrome inspect element whether the particular is applying your given property or not.

Answer (score 3):

Gentleman, I would say there is a very small change in your code.

1. Add additional class besides the material-icon class from (`md-18`, `md-24`, `md-36`, `md-48`) as per your requirement.
2. You have missed one of the closings for div (I have placed a comment in the code).

**Please find below code**

```css
.colored-section {
        background: #888;
      }
      /* Navigation Bar */

      .navbar {
        padding: 0 0 4.5rem;
      }

      .navbar-brand {
        font-family: 'Ubuntu';
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      .navbar-dark .navbar-brand {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .nav-item {
        padding: 0 18px;
      }

      .nav-link {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        font-family: 'Montserrat-Light';
      }

      .material-icons.md-48 {
        font-size: 48px;
      }
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello</title>

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Ubuntu"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <!-- CSS Stylesheets -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <script
      defer
      src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"
    ></script>

    <!-- Google icon -->
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <!-- Bootstrap Scripts -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <section class="colored-section" id="title">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Nav Bar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
          <!-- additional class added along with material-icons -->
          <span class="material-icons md-36">whatshot</span>hello</a>
          <button
            class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02"
          >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#footer">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#cta">Download</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      <!-- forgotten closing for the div -->
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your CSS is inside styles.css then you should include that stylesheet after material icons so that it overwrites. Material icons stylesheet has a default font size of 24px. CSS will always apply last rule it finds in all the stylesheets so if the material font size rule is after, whatever you do "above" won't matter.

Comment: Actually I see you are concatenating classes in the css so you might be just missing that extra class. E.g: md-48. If the both classes are not on the same span tag that rule is not applied. You only have "material-icons" class on that span tag but in your css you have .material-icons.md-48 { font-size: 48px; }. This rule will never be applied because there is not tag with both classes.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to add `.md-48` to your element.

```
      <span class="material-icons">
        whatshot
      </span>hello</a>
```

becomes;

```
      <span class="material-icons md-48">
        whatshot
      </span>hello</a>
```

Remember, when you create a class you have to APPLY the class to the element.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for not changing the size of material-icons is because you didn't include `md` tag in your code. Correct it as I mentioned below. You can add (`md-18, md-24, md-36, md-48`)  as you want.

```
 <span class="material-icons md-48">
```

Your fonts are white. So nothing was shown. So I add background color to your header section. As your wish you can change it also.

```css
 #title{
    background:black;
  }
  .navbar {
  padding: 0 0 4.5rem;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav-item {
  padding: 0 18px;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-family: "Montserrat-Light";
}

.material-icons.md-48 { font-size: 48px; }
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hello</title>

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- CSS Stylesheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>

  <!-- Google icon -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Bootstrap Scripts -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <section class="colored-section" id="title">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Nav Bar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
          <span class="material-icons md-48">
            whatshot
          </span>hello</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#footer">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#cta">Download</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav> </section> </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the size to be 48px you need to add this class 'md-48' to the span like this

```
<span class="material-icons md-48">whatshot</span>
```

if you want it to be 36 just replace it to 'md-36' and so on.

```css
.material-icons.md-18 { font-size: 18px; }
.material-icons.md-24 { font-size: 24px; }
.material-icons.md-36 { font-size: 36px; }
.material-icons.md-48 { font-size: 48px; }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>

  <!-- Google icon -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <span class="material-icons md-48">whatshot</span>
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#footer">Contact <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Download</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  <div class="container">
  <!-- Content here -->
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you forgot link to material themes:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

and a closing div is missing before closing section tag.

Comment: I have the material themes code in my <head></head>

Answer (score 0):

First, to make sure your icon works as it should be, check the following factors:

1. You must use [icon names](https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline) that are font, not custom text

**Example**:

[image]

```
<span class="material-icons">date_range</span>
```

---

2. Check check if your element has a font family of **Material icons**

[image]

---

**Change icon size**:

You need add **md-{number}** class to your icon

```
<span class="material-icons md-18">whatshot</span>
```

Also from the image above you can see that the icon has a size of 24 pixels just change it in your css.

Comment: How can I tell which one is which?

Comment: I changed my answer, let me know if this helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>  
.gfg { 
    width:auto; 
    text-align:center; 
    padding:20px; 
} 
img { 
    max-width:100%; 
    height:auto; 
} 
</style>
```

Comment: Can you add some English text describing how it solves OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `md-48` class to your span element:

```
  <span class="material-icons md-48">
    ...
  </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the snippet below please, you can bypass default `CSS` rules and apply your own on the icons, for example in the snippet below there are some changes so that all `navbar` elements are centered vertically.

```css
/* Navigation Bar */
:root {
  --md-size: 48px;
  --sm-size: 36px;
}
#title {
  background-color:#000;
}
.navbar {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: var(--md-size);
  min-height: var(--md-size);
}
.navbar-brand *{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar-brand .material-icons{
  align-self: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.navbar-brand {
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: bold; 
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  place-content: center space-evenly;
}


.nav-link {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-family: "Montserrat-Light";
}
#title .material-icons {
  font-size: var(--sm-size);
}
#title .material-icons.md-48 {
  font-size: var(--md-size);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- CSS Stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Font Awesome -->
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>

<!-- Google icon -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Bootstrap Scripts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<section class="colored-section" id="title">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Nav Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
      <span class="material-icons md-48">
            whatshot
          </span>
        <span class="material-icons">
            whatshot
          </span>hello</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#footer">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#cta">Download</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```